# Problem with file upload using jquery on ie and chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, upload

I have this simple script

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <input id="File1" type="file" />
</asp:Content>

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#file_upload').fileUpload({
        url: 'UploadHandler.ashx',
        method: 'POST'
        // autoUpload: false,
//        onLoadAll: function (list)
//        {
//            __doPostBack('MainContent_UpdatePanel1', '');
//        },

    });

    $('#File1').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '-100' }); //hack for chrome, in fx enough is jquery hide()

    $('#MainContent_btnUploadFile').click(function ()
    {
        $('#File1').click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the http handler

```
 public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadedfile = context.Request.Files[0];
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I launch this code, in firefox is all ok. In the http handler there is my uploaded file. But in chrome I have exception, because Request.Files has no file. In internet explorer after selected file it is over. It never gets to the handler. Why the hell on diffrent browsers are that much diffrent results? The jquery upload plugin is located here http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload
What can I do with it? Example from plugin page for asp.net works ok on chrome. I think I wrote is in the same way like in this example, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't put "[asp.net]" in your title. It's already in the tags, where it belongs.

Comment: could it be related to https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/185

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, some browsers will send the file in `context.Request.Files("<filename>").InputStream`
Others will use `context.Request.InputStream`

I'm using http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ as the upload control